# OutOfMemoryError when creating many objects

Tags: java

I've created an AI for a game and I'm trying to find the average score of the AI. Since the game has a luck factor I need to repeat the game multiple times to average out the score.

The trouble is the game is quite large and complex so when I try running a sample of say 200 games then I will get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I've tried increasing the amount of memory available with : `-Xmx2048m` in run configurations but this is just a temporary fix and if I want to run a bigger sample then it will fall over.

The code basically goes like:

```
for(int i=0;i<200;i++) {
    game g = new game();
    //some other stuff for collecting data on the score etc.
}
```

Is there anyway I can delete object `g` after each loop so I won't run out of memory?

Comment: It's already deleted. Either your game is too big or there's some bug somewhere else.

Comment: Why are you doing that in a loop, anyway?

Comment: @dystroy I don't think so since it can do like 20 game loops before it will throw the error.

Comment: As soon as you put something else in `g`, it no longer references the previous object. If `g` was the only reference to that object, then that object is gone. But if you're keeping any references in fields, static fields etc., then those referenced objects will not be garbage-collected.

Comment: @John Well, You didn't give us enough code

Comment: @John You probably keep a copy of `g` somewhere, for example where you collect the score.

Comment: @dystroy I'm trying to keep it short since people keep downvoting my questions :/

Comment: @John Garbage collector should handle it but its hard to say without enough code.

Comment: @John Have a look at that : http://sscce.org/ We don't want much code, we want the **minimal** code needed to **reproduce** your problem

Comment: Take a heap dump and analyze it in order to see what consumes so much memory. Maybe you have a memory leak somewhere

Comment: *I'm trying to keep it short since people keep downvoting my questions* people will downvote your questions if they're hardly answerable like this question in its current state. Provide the relevant code, context explanation, etc to understand the problem, reproduce it and provide a solution. Stop thinking about people upvoting/downtoving your questions/answers, just think how this question can be solved and can help somebody else in the future, and you'll be good.

Comment: Just read up on garbage collection in Java, it is too big of a subject to be explained in one answer here (but still you should be able to grasp the fundamentals in an hour or two.)

Comment: And also, what kind of `OutOfMemoryError` are you getting, heap space or perm gen?

Comment: not relative to question, but for AI u should usually factor luck out with a decision tree or min max or ..... (so u need a big code change ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's garbage collection is not deterministic.  That is, there is no guarantee made by the language *when* the garbage collector will delete an object.

However, it is guaranteed that a call to `new` will not throw an `OutOfMemoryError` before trying to free as much memory as possible.  From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html):

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector.

In the following code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    game g = new game();
}
```

the object referenced by `g` becomes unreachable after each iteration of the loop and therefore subject to garbage collection.  If the allocation of a `game` object in the next iteration fails with an `OutOfMemoryError` then you can be certain that the JVM has already tried deleting the old instance but still failed to acquire enough memory.

If your actual code is more complex, be careful, though, not to leak a reference to the `game` that lives longer than the current loop iteration. (For example by inserting it into some list.)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Perhaps it should be if one were to follow the rules 100%, but being a bit pragmatic any answer who will help someone solve their problem is good enough in my book..

Comment: @dystroy Then I misunderstand the question.  Isn't this what was asked for?

Comment: @5gon12eder The problem isn't in the code we see so you can't and you don't solve it. Once we made this point in comment, we should close the question.

Answer (score -2):

Why not declare the variable outside the for loop:

```
game g;
for(int i = 0 ; i< 200; i ++){
g = new game();
//some other stuff for collecting data on the score etc.
}
```

Or Declare the variable as final

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< 200; i ++){
final game g = new game();
//some other stuff for collecting data on the score etc.
}
```

Comment: And how will this change anything ?